# Best practices for setting up a CI server with Jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, server, server-monitoring, ci-server

Problem Statement: I am trying to set up a CI server (on windows 2008 R2) which would run Jenkins and would also be able to collect different metrices that would be useful for monitoring the CI server.

I am not from the operations team hence do not have much knowledge into server monitoring hence seeking help regarding the best practices to set the server up.

I know of below three ways to set up a Jenkins server

1. Run as a background windows service - but it will not help as I need to run the selenium tests and they would fail if jenkins is running as a background service
2. Open a cmd prompt and run java -jar jenkins.war - With this option jenkins is up and running but I am not sure how to include the monitoring portion for jenkins
3. I can set up a apache tomcat and then can run Jenkins inside the tomcat - but in this case also I am not sure of how to collect the data/metrices for server monitoring

Any ideas and pointers would be very helpful for me in setting up the server.

Comment: Do you have any idea what metrics you are looking at? What problems you faced while implementing the Jenkins monitoring?

Comment: I need to set up a monitoring so that the server can be tracked and diagnosed and I do not know about the metrices that can help me achieve this. Hence asking here so that with the ideas I can go ahead and then try to figure out errors if any. This is a totally new area for me as I do not have knowledge on operations at all....